# Complex numbers as exponents

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Is there any formula to calculate $2^i$ for example? What about $x^z$? I was surfing through different pages and I couldn't seem to find a formula like de Moivre's with $z^x$.

Comment: You have to read about multi-valued complex functions. There have been many questions about that on MathSE if you look around. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexExponentiation.html

Comment: This question occurs very frequently. See [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/948844/113214) to a similar question, for example.

Answer (score 9):

By definition, for non-rational exponents,
$$
x^z=e^{z\log(x)}
$$
This definition is fine as far as it goes, but the limitation is on the values of $\log(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{C}$.  Since $e^{2\pi i}=1$, logarithms, as inverses of the exponential function, are unique *up to an integer multiple of $2\pi i$*.

Usually, when the base is a positive real number, we use the real value of the logarithm, so
$$
2^i=e^{i\log(2)}=\cos(\log(2))+i\sin(\log(2))
$$
However, if $2$ is viewed as a complex number, we might equally well say
$$
2^i=e^{i\log(2)-2k\pi}=e^{-2k\pi}\cos(\log(2))+ie^{-2k\pi}\sin(\log(2))
$$
for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Not just "pretty much" ... $e^{z\log(x)}$ **is** the definition of $x^z$.

Comment: @GEdgar: Yes. At first, I did not include, "for non-rational exponents", so the "pretty much" was there to recognize there is another definition for rational exponents. When I added "for non-rational exponents", I should have removed the "pretty much". I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 4):

As with the reals, you want to define $a^b$ as $e^{b\log a}$. The logarithm has issues in the complex plane (you cannot make it continuous) but these difficulties are not seen by the exponential.

The key is the identity $$ e^{it}=\cos t+i\,\sin t.$$ This allows you to define the exponential of any $z=s+it$ via
$$
e^z=e^{s+it}=e^se^{it}=e^s\cos t+i\,e^s\sin t.
$$

In your concrete example, you have 
$$
2^i=e^{i\,\log 2}=\cos(\log 2)+i\,\sin(\log 2).
$$